# How to detect contours without edge detection in opencv?

Tags: opencv

I just want to extract contours of a text from an image. I dont want to do edge detection here. But without edge detection the contours of text are not clear. How can i achieve this? Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid edge detection? I think that any kind of contour extraction involves edge detection on some level.

Comment: what about adaptive threshold ?

Comment: difficult to answer without knowing what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks guys. bjoemz, if i use edge detection, the contours what am getting are not so perfect. In some places the texts are clipped out when i drawn it using extracted contours. Ok, is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Quentin Geissman, i will check this man. Thanks.

Comment: peterretief, i want to find out the contours of texts available in image. If i drawn that contour, it should not be clipped out. It should give exact boundary of text.